# Call to a member function links() on array in laravel 5.7

Tags: laravel, join, eloquent, hyperlink, pagination

I am using pagination in Laravel 5.7 to build an application. However, when I add a pagination link on view, it shows an error **Call to a member function links() on array**.
This is what the array looks like when i try to echo it in the view:

```
{
  "current_page": 1,
  "data": [
    {
      "stk_id": 7,
      "stk_name": "shafi",
      "stk_last_name": "razai",
      "stk_email": "shafi@gmail.com",
      "stk_phone": "1234567890",
      "stk_gender": "male"
    },
    {
      "stk_id": 9,
      "stk_name": "ali",
      "stk_last_name": "ahmadi",
      "stk_email": "ali@gmail.com",
      "stk_phone": "0987654321",
      "stk_gender": "male"
    }
  ],
  "first_page_url": "http://localhost/accountingLaravel/countings?page=1",
  "from": 1,
  "last_page": 2,
  "last_page_url": "http://localhost/accountingLaravel/countings?page=2",
  "next_page_url": "http://localhost/accountingLaravel/countings?page=2",
  "path": "http://localhost/accountingLaravel/countings",
  "per_page": 2,
  "prev_page_url": null,
  "to": 2,
  "total": 4
}
```

This is my controller index fuction

```
public function index(){

    $countings = DB::table('countings')
                ->join('stackholders', 'countings.stk_id', '=', 'stackholders.stk_id')
                ->orderBy('countings.c_date', 'desc')
                ->select('stackholders.*')
                ->paginate(2);

    $countings = DB::select('SELECT countings.* , stackholders.stk_id , stackholders.stk_name ,stackholders.stk_last_name FROM countings INNER JOIN stackholders ON countings.stk_id = stackholders.stk_id order by c_id desc');

    $stackholders = Stackholder::orderBy('stk_name')->get();

    $a = array(
        'countings' => $countings , 
        'stackholders' => $stackholders
    );
    return view('countings.index')->with($a);

}
```

And this is in my view page where I loop through the code

```
@if (count($countings)> 0 )
    @foreach ($countings as $counting)
        <tr>
           <td>{{$counting->stk_name . " " . $counting->stk_last_name}}</td>
           <td>{{$counting->c_desc}}</td>
           <td>{{$counting->c_date}}</td>
           <td>{{$counting->c_state}}</td>
           <td>{{$counting->c_value}}</td>
        </tr>
     @endforeach

     {{ $countings->links() }}
```

Can someone please suggest how to solve this issue?

Comment: Error is very obvious. You are calling `$counting->links()`. `$counting` is an array, which you got by using `DB::select()`. Why not use Eloquent instead of queries?

Comment: thank you so much. I have already done it.